# Magento 2 admin panel integration is missing

Tags: magento2.3, system-configuration, integration

does anyone know how to fix a system error. I have asked someone to install Magento 2, but it seems like the system integration section is missing.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different variables that a problem like this could be related to. Can you share what kind of environment its hosted on? Local or hosted on the web? What version of Magento 2 exactly are you running? Is it a blank store or was the sample data imported?

If hosted on the web what kind of server is it on? Some hosting company's have server configs that are not magneto 2 friendly so it could seem to be working ok but various issues can arise later with these kind of hosting environments.

How well do you know Magento btw? If you don't have much experience with it, it can be a little overwhelming at fist. If you don't know M2 very well I'd be happy to take a quick look at your set up.

Comment: Hello Climbah thank you so much for your response. To be honest I don't know Magento so well. I host my Magento 2.3.3 on OVH dedicated server, because they offer more affordable RAM. It is not a blank store but has quite a lot of products. 

Actually I received this error while connecting with a third party API to upload products to my Magento store. I tried to ask people if they could solve this problem, then their answer leads me to the system integration. 

Here is the error: https://www.hebescosmetics.com/rest/uk_en/V1/products/attributes
Do you mind taking a look?
Thanks in advance

Comment: whats your email address?

Comment: Still happy to look at this issue for you and see if I can help. Cant do much without access though. If you gimme your email addy I can message you